# How to test if my translations are show up on the app

Tags: android, translation, in-app

I have just integrated android in-app billing sdk to my app. I am trying to display the title and description of the unmanaged in app products to Indian language Hindi. I have translated the english to Hindi script, now I need to test it. Is there a way I can specify on my app, or the phone to show hindi script where available ?

[image: notice the "Subject to realization, usage Taxeeta for 3 calender months]

I have translated this text on my google play developer account.

PS : Ignore the `Item unavailable` error for now, it there since I have just set the unmanaged in app products to Active, it will take a while to sync up I guess. I also have a published app version x without BillingPermission. Although my version x+1 (unpublished) apk has been uploaded for testing and configuration purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way of changing the phones locale? If so, try an app like [Set Locale and Language](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bruce.setlocale)

Good luck!

Comment: I am looking for hindi script, my phone does not have that as a choice.

Comment: you can still set it and your app will display it.